# Error with Too many positional arguements in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class AndroidNotificationDetails{
  /// Constructs an instance of [AndroidNotificationDetails].
  const AndroidNotificationDetails(
    this.channelId,
    this.channelName, {
   
...
```

it gets me an error of

```
lib/Notification%20Manager/notification_manager.dart:12:42: Error: Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
```

I tried Reviewing my code but nothing worked
Please Help.

Comment: Alt Click on the AndroidNotificationDetails and check what arguments it is waiting.

Comment: Please share the code snippet of the usage

Comment: And the code where you're getting this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name `AndroidNotificationDetails` is same as the function name.

Change the class name, it would work fine.

Hope it helps!